# Problems importing from python package (local vs on the python path)

Tags: python, python-import

I am unable to get the following things to work simultaneously in Python2.7:

- import submodules from a local package
- import submodules from the package when it is on the PYTHONPATH

I have set up the sample directory structure as in the [python docs for packages](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#packages)

```
 cd tmp
 mkdir sound
 mkdir sound/formats
 mkdir sound/effects
 mkdir sound/filters
 cd sound
 touch __init__.py
 cp !$ formats/
 cp __init__.py formats/
 cp __init__.py effects/
 cp __init__.py filters/
 echo "def echofilter(): return(1) " > effects/echo.py
 cd ../..
```

So, I end up with:

```
$ ls tmp/sound
effects/  filters/  formats/  __init__.py
```

If I make the package local, as it would be if it were acting as a git submodule, for instance, ie by `cd tmp`, the following is successful:

```
$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
>>> from sound.effects import echo
>>>
```

Yet if I am located somewhere else (`cd ..`), and I put the package on my PYTHONPATH, I cannot import as in the docs:

```
[~/tmp]$ cd ..
[~]$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Oct 14 2015, 16:09:02) 
[GCC 5.2.1 20151010] on linux2
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/home/meuser/tmp/sound')
>>> from sound.effects import echo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sound.effects
>>> sys.path.append('/home/meuser/tmp/sound/effects')
>>> from sound.effects import echo
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named sound.effects
```

So how am I supposed to arrange things?

Comment: So let me get this straight: you want to be able to import this package you've made from anywhere on the machine?

Comment: Yes. I have certain packages that I maintain and use for lots of projects. I put their location in my PYTHONPATH (isn't that what it's for?), set in my bash configuration.  In fact, that's how I've done it for many years, but I never used dots to specify submodules (sound.effects). Instead, I just had a bunch of files (modules) at the same level under sound/ , from which I would import explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

Ah! If it's a package, I need the folder *containing* the package (ie ~/tmp/) in my path, not the folder of the package itself (~/tmp/sound). Thus, the following works:

```
>>> import sys
>>> sys.path.append('/home/meuser/tmp/')
>>> from sound.effects import echo
```

Now I believe this solves all my recent conundrums..